# Prove: product of difference of variances is greater than square of difference of covariances

Tags: variance, random-variable, covariance, proof, probability-inequalities

Given random variables $X_1$,$X_2$,$Y_1$,$Y_2$, such that
$$
\text{Var}(X_1) > \text{Var}(X_2),\text{Var}(Y_1) > \text{Var}(Y_2).
$$

Then does the following hold?

$$
[\text{Var}(X_1) - \text{Var}(X_2)][\text{Var}(Y_1) - \text{Var}(Y_2)] \ge [\text{Cov}(X_1,Y_1)-\text{Cov}(X_2,Y_2)]^2
$$

Comment: Consider the limiting case of equal variances. You would be asserting that the two covariances must then be the same, which obviously is false.

Comment: Wouldn't equal variances violate the first premise? One variance is greater than the other.

Comment: I think what @whuber is saying is that if you assume that the variance are very close to each other, then this necessitates that the covariances are close to each other, which isn't necessarily true (think multivariate normal)